# Does Ubuntu Installer automatically install in "/"?

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, system-installation

The first time i installed Ubuntu Gnome 13.10, Ichecked the option <kbd>Something Else</kbd> in the ubuntu installer and went through the partition process `/`, `/home`, `swap`.

Now, after a bad taste while trying *Gnome 3.10*, I decided to clean the slate and use <kbd>Reinstall ubuntu gnome</kbd> *(the one that doesn't mess with documents)* and something crossed my mind when i clicked <kbd>Next</kbd>:

*Does ubuntu installer automatically recognize and reinstall in (/) or should i have used gparted and do it manually?*

Comment: Thanks for that, i decided to go manual this time, by the way, should i assign a mount point to my backup partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should do yes - I think it also overwrites any `/boot`, `/var`, etc partitions as well, as long as they are not `/home`. To quote [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving):

> Setting up /home on a separate partition is beneficial because your
>   settings, files, and desktop will be maintained if you upgrade,
>   (re)install Ubuntu or another distro. This works because /home has a
>   subdirectory for each user's settings and files which contain all the
>   data & settings of that user. Telling Ubuntu to use an existing home
>   partition can be done by selecting "Manual Partitioning" during the
>   installation of Ubuntu and specifying that you want your home
>   partitions mount point to be /home, ensure you mark your /home
>   partition not be formatted in the process.

So you should to be able to reinstall from other install disk types, e.g.

- [Normal/Vanilla Desktop Ubuntu install](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) - Unity Desktop Environment
- [KUbuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu) - KDE Desktop Environment
- [XUbuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) - XFCE Desktop Environment

and other [Ubuntu Derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives). Whether they can automatically resinstall, or you have to do it manually, I don't know.

May I also mention that even though it is called Ubuntu Gnome, you can find a massive list of other Desktop Environments to Gnome [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available). [Unity](https://askubuntu.com/a/65108/178596) is the default one for Ubuntu.